# Replacing Double Backslash Double Quotes with Sed Linux

Tags: linux, sed, replace, backslash

I want to replace \\" before processing my file with \\' and then after processing the file I need to replace \\' back to \\".

Input file testreplace

```
"dsd" "\N" "gary\\""
"ghj" "fandango\\\"" "\N"
"jjj"" "hjh" "gfgfgfg\\"
"ee" "gg\"" "\N"
```

Issue while replacing //" to //' using sed. I have used the below command.

```
sed "s/\\\\\"/\\\\\'/g" testreplace > testreplaceopt
```

but this command is replacing \" with \' also but I want to replace when only two backslashes come

After processing the file I am trying to replace \\' back with \\" using below command

```
sed "s/\\\\\'/\\\\\"/g" testreplaceopt > testreplace_back
```

but its not getting replaced

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It was my bad, changed my question. Thanks @jww

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different delimiters can be used in sed substitution.

Use hash character or plus character in sed statement and use single quote in double quote.

Other thing which I want to mention is using double backslash characters instead of using one for each backslash character in the single quote statement.

For instance:

```
$ cat /tmp/aa |sed -r 's+\\\\"+\\\\'"'"'+g'
"dsd" "\N" "gary\\'"
"ghj" "fandango\\\'" "\N"
"jjj"" "hjh" "gfgfgfg\\'
"ee" "gg\"" "\N"
```

or if you want to use '+' char instead of '/' in sed statement:

```
$ cat /tmp/aa |sed -r 's+\\\\"+\\\\'"'"'+g'
"dsd" "\N" "gary\\'"
"ghj" "fandango\\\'" "\N"
"jjj"" "hjh" "gfgfgfg\\'
"ee" "gg\"" "\N"
```

[Using different delimiters in sed](https://backreference.org/2010/02/20/using-different-delimiters-in-sed/)

I hope it helps

Comment: but is is replacing "gg\"" in the fourth row, that I dont want. I want to replace only with two backslashes.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot. It would be helpful if you can explain also :).

Comment: Thanks Ali. I got it. it was shell causing issue in interpreting the backslashes. It is working now in both the cases.